# Аналог события mozbrowserclose для Chrome последней версии

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Событие описано тут https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events
Не удается найти аналог для chrome. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел на просторах.

Аналог с участием `jQuery`. Проверял в `Chrome`, `Firefox`.

```js
function Unloader(){
 
    var o = this;
 
    this.unload = function(evt)
    {
        var message = "Вы уверены, что хотите покинуть страницу. Ведь данные могут потеряться?";
        if (typeof evt == "undefined") {
            evt = window.event;
        }
        if (evt) {
            evt.returnValue = message;
        }
        return message;
    }
 
    this.resetUnload = function()
    {
        $(window).off('beforeunload', o.unload);
 
         setTimeout(function(){
            $(window).on('beforeunload', o.unload);
        }, 2000);
    }
 
    this.init = function()
    {
         
        $(window).on('beforeunload', o.unload);
 
        $('a').on('click', function(){o.resetUnload});
        $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(){o.resetUnload});
        $(document).on('keydown', function(event){
            if((event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 116) || event.keyCode == 116){
                o.resetUnload;
            }
        });
    }
    this.init();
}
 
$(function(){
    if(typeof window.obUnloader != 'object')
    {
        window.obUnloader = new Unloader();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

В `Firefox` сообщение нельзя подменить. Оно будет стандартным `о не сохраненных данных`.

Если запустить скрипт, текущее окно при обновлении/закрытии будет спрашивать пользователя, о его желании продолжить действие